# pairedRDD from wholeTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to work with wholeTextfiles and get a pairedRDD from the data but as i am new I am a bit confused with this :
here is the code:

```
val wholefiles = sc.wholeTextFiles("sqoop_import/orders")
wholefiles: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = sqoop_import/orders MapPartitionsRDD[72] at wholeTextFiles at <console>:27

wholefiles.take(5).foreach(println)
(hdfs://filename, 1, 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED
2,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,256,PENDING_PAYMENT
3,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,12111,COMPLETE
4,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,8827,CLOSED)
```

How can I get a pairedRDD with column4 and column1 from the above data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code -

```
wholeTextFiles.map(record=>record._2)
              .map(lines=>lines.split("\n"))
              .flatMap(lines=>lines)
              .map(line=>line.split(","))
              .map(fields=>(fields(3),fields(0)))
              .collect()
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Nikil,i get this error:<console>:29: error: value split is not a member of (String, String)
         val x = wholefiles.map(line=>line.split(",")).

Comment: Hi Nav, can you provide your input file or few records from input file?

Comment: 1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED
2,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,256,PENDING_PAYMENT
3,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,12111,COMPLETE
4,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,8827,CLOSED
5,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11318,COMPLETE
6,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,7130,COMPLETE
7,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,4530,COMPLETE
8,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,2911,PROCESSING
9,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,5657,PENDING_PAYMENT
10,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,5648,PENDING_PAYMENT

Comment: I did not notice that you are required to use wholeTextFiles api. I have edited my answer, it works for above data set.